Théorème de Schwarz
In my class and elsewhere, the proof of Schwarz’s theorem is not so hard but also not that obvious. Yet by doing some calculations I came across an argument that makes things simpler, but there must be some mistake otherwise that’s what we’d have been taught. I explain.
We consider $E$ and $F$ two real normed vector spaces, $U$ an open subset of $E$ and $f:U\longrightarrow F$ a map. Let $a\in U$. For all $h,k\in E$ such that $a+h,a+k\in U$, we denote
\begin{equation}
\Delta f(a)(h):=f(a+h)-f(a)\\
\Delta^2f(a)(h,k) := \left(\Delta[\Delta f](a)(k)\right)(h).
\end{equation}
Then we notice that
\begin{align}
\Delta^2f(a)(h,k)
&= \Delta f(a+k)(h)-\Delta f(a)(h)\\
&= f(a+k+h)-f(a+k)-f(a+h)+f(a)\\
&= f(a+h+k)-f(a+h)-f(a+k)+f(a)\\
&= \Delta^2f(a)(k,h)
\end{align}
so $\Delta^2f(a)$ is “symmetric” (or “commutative” I don’t know what is the correct terminology). Suppose that $f$ is twice differentiable at $a$. Then for all $h\in E$ near $0$ such that $a+h\in U$,
\begin{equation}\mathrm df(a)h = \Delta f(a)(h)+o\left(\lVert h\rVert\right)\end{equation}
and there exists $V\subseteq U$ a neighbourhood of $a$ such that for all $k\in E$ near $0$ such that $a+k\in V$
\begin{align}
\mathrm d^2f(a)(h,k)
&= \left(\mathrm d[\mathrm df](a)k\right)h\\
&= \mathrm df(a+k)h-\mathrm df(a)h+o\left(\lVert k\rVert\right)\\
&= \Delta f(a+k)(h)+o\left(\lVert h\rVert\right)-\Delta f(a)(h)-o\left(\lVert h\rVert\right)+o\left(\lVert k\rVert\right)\\
&= \Delta f(a+k)(h)-\Delta f(a)(h)+o\left(\lVert h\rVert\right)+o\left(\lVert k\rVert\right)\\
&= \Delta^2f(a)(h,k)+ o\left(\lVert(h,k)\rVert\right)
\end{align}
however the right hand side is “symmetric”, so there must be the same for $\mathrm d^2f(a)(h,k)$ isn’t it ?
Recall :

We say that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if there exists a continuous linear map $L:E\longrightarrow F$ such that for all $h\in E$ near $0$ such that $a+h\in U$,
\begin{equation}f(a+h)=f(a)+Lh+o\left(\lVert h\rVert\right).\end{equation}
$L$ is the differential of $f$ at $a$, denoted by $\mathrm df(a)$. We say that $f$ is differentiable when it is differentiable at any point. In this case, we have a map
\begin{array}{rccl}
\mathrm df: & U & \longrightarrow & \mathcal L(E,F)\\ & x & \longmapsto & \mathrm df(x)
\end{array}
called differential of $f$.
We say that $f$ is twice differentiable at $a$ if $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood $V \subseteq U $ of $a$ and $\mathrm df$ differentiable at $a$, the second differential of $f$ at $a$ is $\mathrm d[\mathrm df](a)\in\mathcal L(E,\mathcal L(E,F))$. Looking at the definition, the notation is not simple :
$\left(\mathrm d[\mathrm df](a)k\right)h$, but this expression is linear in $h$ and in $k$, and indeed we can isometrically identify $\mathrm d[\mathrm df](a)$ to a continuous bilinear map. Then we will say that the map denoted by $\mathrm d^2f(a)\in\mathcal L^2(E,F)$ and defined by
\begin{equation}\mathrm d^2f(a)(h,k):=\left(\mathrm d[\mathrm df](a)k\right)h,\quad\forall(h,k)\in E^2\end{equation}
is the second differential of $f$ at $a$.


Please write in English.

Post in English, please. See What is Math SE's policy on posts in languages other than English? and Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?.

Wrote your $o$s in more detail to understand where your "proof" fails. For instance your first $o(|k|)$ depends on $h$, a priori non-uniformly. That said, see https://fr.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/Calcul_différentiel/Théorèmes_utiles#Théorème_de_Schwarz

@MartinR Thank you, I will next time. I wasn’t sure.

@AnneBauval I understand now where is the douille, thanks !

Please write down very carefully what your $\Delta^2f$ has to do with differentiating $Df: U\to L(E,F)$.
